# How to manage money with no expenses

Tags: investment-strategies, checking-account

Suppose a person has $165K in his checking account and has no expenses (e.g living with parents, home cooked meals, etc.).

What would be the best way to distribute/use this money? Should some of it be moved out of the checking account?

Should he use a credit card vs a debit card in the majority of cases to make purchases?

Comment: What are your goals?  Make more money?  Distribute to charity? ...

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose a person has $165K in his checking account and has no expenses
> (e.g living with parents, home cooked meals, etc.).

Unless the money is in a bank that pays interest on checking accounts, that money is not going to grow at all. So at a minimum it should be transferred to a savings account. Check with the bank there may be choices regarding rates. Some banks will pay higher rates for large account balances. Some will offer CDs or time deposits that will pay a higher rate, but those require a commitment of months or years to get those rates.

> What would be the best way to distribute/use this money? Should some
> of it be moved out of the checking account?

It depends on the goals of the money. Is this a temporary situation, or is the money supposed to last for years or decades?

Regarding things like investments: Those make sense if the money isn't needed now, or needed soon. But if the money is going to be used to buy a house next year, and they are living in their parents house to save, then investing is too risky with a short time horizon.

> Should he use a credit card vs a debit card in the majority of cases
> to make purchases?

If the person has a credit card, then there are better protections with the credit card. A debit card allows somebody to tap into the checking account. If there is fraud the checking account could be empty until the issue is resolved. IF the credit card is stolen, the money is still in the bank while the issues are resolved with the credit card company.

Of course if the person doesn't currently have income they might have a hard time getting a credit card if they don't already have one. There are options such as a secured card, or a joint card that could allow them to get a credit card.

Comment: A great answer to both questions. I can see a vote to close as "needs focus" is there. If closed and OP doesn't edit, we can edit to keep the first half and save much of this good answer. (I'm abstaining)

Answer (score 0):

Well, inflation is expected at 2% or more but there is no safe place to even get 2% interest. An interest-rate-hedged corporate bond fund could get about 1.6% interest. Basically, the investor should invest in what they are interested-in or hedge what they are worried about. A sell of a 2-year Treasury future, or a buy of a 2-year Treasury rate future, could possibly simply hedge inflation.

Stocks are risky but good for long-term investments. I would favor an equity-income category.

Basically, have both a bank account with a debit card and a brokerage account or mutual-fund account linked to the bank account.